# c++ ffmpeg api get video stream from https link

Tags: c++, video, https, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to read https video link using the function av_format_open_input() but the function return a negative value.
Here is my code:

```
av_register_all();
avcodec_register_all();
avformat_network_init();
const char * url = "https://r1---sn ...";

AVFormatContext * pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();

int ret = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, url, NULL, NULL);
```

This code worked with a local file as url but as soon as I give a https url it doesnt work anymore.
thanks
**[edit]**
I found only this: [ffserver.c](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/ffserver_8c-source.html)
But it uses a .ffm file as input. Any exemple or help on how to implement HttpContext (if HttpContext is needed here) would be great.
**[update]**
I ended using libvlc which seems to be much easier but the way to do it using ffmpeg could still be interesting. See my other post if interested: [Get frame from video with libvlc smem and convert it to opencv Mat. (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092940/get-frame-from-video-with-libvlc-smem-and-convert-it-to-opencv-mat-c)

Comment: A URI link by its self wouldn't be a valid stream. You'll need to implement a [HTTPContext](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structHTTPContext.html), and pass [HTTPContext->stream->feed_filename](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/ffserver_8c_source.html#l02791) to `avformat_open_input`.

Comment: Any clue on how to implement the HTTPContext ? (Can't find any exemple)