# working with VLC smem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, libvlc

I'm trying to do something like this post :
[Get frame from video with libvlc smem and convert it to opencv Mat. (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092940/get-frame-from-video-with-libvlc-smem-and-convert-it-to-opencv-mat-c)

I can't quite understand the code in this part :

```
 sprintf(smem_options
      , "#transcode{vcodec=RV24}:smem{"
         "video-prerender-callback=%lld,"
         "video-postrender-callback=%lld,"
         "video-data=%lld,"
         "no-time-sync},"
      , (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)&cbVideoPrerender
      , (long long int)(intptr_t)(void*)&cbVideoPostrender //This would normally be useful data, 100 is just test data
      , (long long int)200 //Test data
      );
```

It says `video-data=%lld` . What does it mean? Where is it taking data from?

I am getting my file using a file dialog . Can I pass that file to video-data?

Comment: check out [man 3 sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rather than using the `smem` output driver of VLC, i would suggest to interact directly with `libvlc`, via the [mediaplayer](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html) interface:

```
/* user_data is the pointer we passed to `video_set_callbacks()` */
void*lock_frame(void*user_data, void**planes) {
   /* make '*plane* point to a memory you want the video-data rendered to */
  *planes=user_data->img;
  return user_data->pic;
}
void unlock_frame(void *user_data, void *picture, void *const *planes) {
   /* image rendered into (*planes)==user_data->img; */
}

unsigned format_callback(void**user_data_ptr; char*chroma, unsigned *width, unsigned *height, unsigned *pitches, unsigned *lines) {
   mydata_t*user_data=(mydata_t*)(*user_data_ptr);

   /* set the output format to RGBA */
   memcpy(chroma, "RV32", 4); /* 'RV32' is 'RGBA'
   /* leave dimensions intact, but store them
    * now's the time to resize user_data->img to hold that much memory
    */
   user_data->width =*width;
   user_data->height=*height;
   *pitches=(*width)*4; /* 4 is the pixel size for RGBA */
   *lines=*height;

   return 1;
}


vlc_inst=libvlc_new (0, 0);
libvlc_media_t*media = libvlc_media_new_location (vlc_inst, location);
libvlc_media_player_t*mplayer=libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(media);
libvlc_video_set_callbacks(mplayer,
                         lock_frame, unlock_frame,
                         0, user_data);
libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks(data->m_mediaplayer, format_callback,0);

libvlc_media_player_play(mplayer);

/* the media-player will call 
 *  - format_callback() with a format suggestion which you can adjust to your needs
 *  - lock_frame()/unlock_frame() whenever a new frame has arrived.
 * once you are done, call: */

libvlc_media_player_stop(mplayer);
libvlc_release(vlc_inst);
```

Comment: tnx for reply . sorry but i'm not much c++ user so i have some simple (i guess) questions :D . what is user_data ? do you mean  *planes=user_data->img; instead of  *plane=user_data->img; ?what return does , isn't your function void ?  can you provide me with a more completed code please .

Comment: `user_data` is just a pointer to any of *your* data; yes, it should have read `*planes`; no, the function returns `void*` (a pointer to an unspecified type); no, I [cannot](https://github.com/umlaeute/Gem/tree/master/plugins/videoVLC)

Comment: this method only works if u use **gem plugin**. u have to use **pixBlock** . i don't think that's necessary because libvlc is able to do that . u can save a video to image sequence . u can take snapshot . so u can extract picture from video in libvlc , but i dunno how .

Comment: you asked for a complete example and i provided one from real world; which is embedded in another framework (Gem); the use of the *libvlc-API* is really straightforward

Comment: tnx for that . i figured it out . this is really good way but in this way u cannot find video width and height and u have to use predefined width and height .

Comment: @user2798392 actually you can use the native width/height by using `libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks()`; i've updated my simple example

Comment: this is great . it works . but another little issue . the height in format_callback has margin or something and its not real height of my video .

Comment: btw, if an answer has helped you, you migh consider *upvoting* and/or *accepting* it