# Python3 PyQt5 play mp4 compiled module

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtmultimedia

I'm building a desktop GUI app which includes MP4 (audio/visual) files. I have compiled them using pyrcc5 however the way the app is coded so far, using PyVLC, it can't play the videos as compiled modules - I don't want users to copy or replace the videos. What are my options within PyQt5 as far as playing compiled video files are concerned? If I need additional codecs, where would I get these?

Thank you for all constructive feedback.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Get rid of PyVLC and use QtMultimedia (which obviously has built-in support for resource files). Otherwise you'll have to write a whole load of ugly ctypes code to read from a file-like object (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35662828/984421), for example).

Comment: @ekhumoro I realised that using QSound a compiled audio file (WAV format only and not MP3) could be played but as I couldn't find anything about playing compiled video files I was stuck. Your advice, as ever, is exemplary