# Using python vlc play_buffer example

Tags: python, windows, vlc

The code i am trying to run is:

[link](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/master/examples/play_buffer.py)

The output when running this:

`python play_buffer.py C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\SKAI_PODCAST\1821\`

is

```
[000001aa61bb89f0] imem demux error: Invalid get/releaspress enter to quite function pointers
[000001aa61bb7620] imem stream error: Invalid get/release function pointers
OPEN 1831289042448 <vlc.LP_c_void_p object at 0x000001AA6195CBC8> <vlc.LP_c_ulonglong object at 0x000001AA6195CC48>
read file list
playlist:
READ 1831289042448 <ctypes.LP_c_char object at 0x000001AA6195CBC8> 16777216
reading file [0] file list is over
just read f0B
[000001aa61bb8c90] mjpeg demux error: cannot peek
CLOSE 1831289042448
releasing stream provider
[000001aa61baf040] main input error: ╬Ω ╬╡╬ψ╧Δ╬┐╬┤╧Ν╧Γ ╧Δ╬▒╧Γ ╬┤╬╡╬╜ ╬╝╧Α╬┐╧Β╬╡╬ψ ╬╜╬▒ ╬▒╬╜╬┐╬╣╧Θ╧Ε╬╡╬ψ
[000001aa61baf040] main input error: O VLC ╬┤╬╡╬╜ ╬╡╬ψ╬╜╬▒╬╣ ╬┤╧Ζ╬╜╬▒╧Ε╧Ν╬╜ ╬╜╬▒ ╬▒╬╜╬┐╬ψ╬╛╬╡╬╣ ╧Ε╬┐ MRL 'imem://'. ╬Χ╬╗╬φ╬│╬╛╧Ε╬╡ ╧Ε╬┐ ╬║╬▒╧Ε╬▒╬│╧Β╬▒╧Η╬┐╬╗╧Ν╬│╬╣╬┐ ╬│╬╣╬▒ ╬╗╬╡╧Α╧Ε╬┐╬╝╬φ╧Β╬╡╬╣╬╡╧Γ.
```

I have opened a github issue: **https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/issues/150**

What can i do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes
import io
import sys
import time

import vlc

MediaOpenCb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint64))
MediaReadCb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_ssize_t, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char), ctypes.c_size_t)
MediaSeekCb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_uint64)
MediaCloseCb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p)


def media_open_cb(opaque, data_pointer, size_pointer):
    data_pointer.contents.value = opaque
    size_pointer.contents.value = sys.maxsize
    return 0


def media_read_cb(opaque, buffer, length):
    stream=ctypes.cast(opaque,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.py_object)).contents.value
    new_data = stream.read(length)
    for i in range(len(new_data)):
        buffer[i]=new_data[i]
    return len(new_data)


def media_seek_cb(opaque, offset):
    stream=ctypes.cast(opaque,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.py_object)).contents.value
    stream.seek(offset)
    return 0


def media_close_cb(opaque):
    stream=ctypes.cast(opaque,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.py_object)).contents.value
    stream.close()


callbacks = {
    'open': MediaOpenCb(media_open_cb),
    'read': MediaReadCb(media_read_cb),
    'seek': MediaSeekCb(media_seek_cb),
    'close': MediaCloseCb(media_close_cb)
}

def main(path):
    stream = open(path, 'rb')
    instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = instance.media_player_new()
    media = instance.media_new_callbacks(callbacks['open'], callbacks['read'], callbacks['seek'], callbacks['close'], ctypes.cast(ctypes.pointer(ctypes.py_object(stream)), ctypes.c_void_p))
    player.set_media(media)
    player.play()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        path = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        print('Usage: {0} <path>'.format(__file__))
        sys.exit(1)

    main(path)
```

I don't know why the above code works (maybe a ctypes issue), but i found the code in my answer in [stackoverflow link](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662828/passing-file-like-objects-to-ctypes-callbacks)