# How to take a snapshot of libvlc player and convert it to Mat object

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, libvlc

I am sorry if my question is not easy to understand, I am French and new to C++ programming...

I have searched all the day a way to take regular snapshots / read the stream from a `libvlc_media_player` player and convert it into `cv::Mat` images but I could not find anything functionnal.

The function `libvlc_video_take_snapshot` seems to be able to save snapshots only in files.

I don't know if I have to do an intermediate conversion (such as rendering this first into an SDL_Texture / a QFrame) before being able to get a Mat image.

I there a way to do this ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32826441/4064749

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23094011/4064749